# How to simulate WiFi going out of range by turning on/off Access Point on my Linux device?

Tags: wifi, access-point

<strike>I'm not running hostapd and can't install it.</strike>

I'm trying to turn off a wireless access point from my device such that any third party devices that are currently connected to it drop the connection.

I've tried `ifconfig wlan1 down` which prevents data being exchanged but the connected third party device still thinks it's connected to my device.

This differs to if I physically walk out of range with the third party device. In this situation the signal strength of the connection reduces until eventually the connection is dropped entirely.

So, is there a way for me to stop broadcasting a WiFi signal via the terminal?

Comment: How is that AP set up on your device, if you're not using hostapd? Are you sure wlan1 is the interface for the AP? Because setting it down *should* prevent any communication, just like going out of range. Besides figuring out what is actually going on so you can properly set the right device down, using `rfkill` might also be an option.

Comment: My mistake, I am actually using hostapd. I managed to solve this by simply using `systemctl stop hostapd`. Interesting to note that the results do differ between using the `ifconfig wlan1 down` and `systemctl stop hostapd` though. Using `ifconfig` stops the data transferring but keeps the connection alive whereas using `hostapd` completely shuts down the connection. The WiFi interface is definitely `wlan1` as reported by `iwconfig`.